# Python/Flask web development

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, web-deployment

I using flask web development to create a mini-web with python 2.7.

```
import settings

from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(settings)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

@app.route("/login")
def login_template():
    return render_template("login.html") 

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run()
```

The `@app.route("/")` is working perfectly fine but i got an error in `@app.route("/login")` because im tryng to `render_template("login.html")`.

The file is in a directory `/templates/login.html` in the same working directory

I got this error:

https://i.gyazo.com/761c169e0d55de45e3dd6c7af346c48c.png

https://i.gyazo.com/571c079b44c6216612c16798d57d200a.png

Comment: The same traceback is printed to the console, as text. Please copy and paste that into your question.

Comment: Your error is caused by the *contents of the template*. You are using `url_for()` wrong somewhere. Without the template, we can't say anything more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of the `url_for` includes a provider parameter, but your code doesn't use that.

Please change accordingly

```
@app.route('/login/')
@app.route('/login/<provider>')
def login_template(provider=None):
    # do something
```